# Using SFTP with SQL Server Integration Services in short steps

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sftp

I want to use SFTP with SQL Server Integration Services in short time.   Since the data is customer information we cannot pass this sensitive information via email and the company's privacy policy won't permit the vendor to write directly to the SQL Server database. The solution we came up with is to use SFTP to get the files from the vendor and also use SQL Server Integration Services to load the data to the database. We want this to all be integrated into an SSIS package, but SSIS doesn't have a native SFTP option.  How can this be done?
I have to mention that the latest method we were using was downloading raw data files from a ftp server, now the approach changed and those files exist on a SFTP server. So, I need an easy-to-use solution to ETL those files to my database via SSIS. As is known, SSIS doesn't have a SFTP connection

[Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3435/using-sftp-with-sql-server-integration-services/) is a website that use this method but this is too long with many steps.
totally I need a way so that finishing packages as soon as possible.

Comment: Your question is imo unclear or too broad or even both. What are you asking for specifically? How to load contents of files from SFTP server to SQL database?

Comment: I have to mention that the latest method we were using was downloading raw data files from a ftp server, now the approach changed and those files exist on a SFTP server. So, I need an easy-to-use solution to ETL those files to my database via SSIS. As is known, SSIS doesn't have a SFTP connection manager.

Comment: Please do not post information/clarification in comments. Edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: There's no reason SFTP should block development of 150 packages. Make the one package that does SFTP and accepts parameters of user/password/sourceFolder/targetFolder/fileMask Now you have a generic, re-usable component all the packages can invoke

Comment: Forgot 150 package

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a workflow that downloads files from FTP (to a local temporary location?) and then imports those files to SQL, and you just want to replace the FTP download with SFTP download (keeping the import step intact), you can:

- use just use the *Execute Process* task to execute any commandline SFTP client to perform the download.

  I have a guide written for my WinSCP SFTP client that does that: [SFTP Task for SSIS/SSDT](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis).

  You will find zillions of questions here or elsewhere showing how to write a script (Windows batch file) for SFTP download (using WinSCP, OpenSSH `sftp` or other clients). This is not SSIS-specific.
- or use *Script* task to use any SFTP .NET library/assembly you like.

  I also have a guide for WinSCP .NET assembly:
  [Using WinSCP .NET Assembly from SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis)

  Again, you will find zillions of questions here and elsewhere showing how to implement an SFTP download in .NET/C#/whatever. Only SSIS-specific part of this is having the code/script added to SSIS and loading the SFTP library/assembly into SSIS (both covered in the previous link).